# [FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).]

Tags: firebase, react-native

**This Error Show In react-native please Give Me Solution**
Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app). import * as firebase from "firebase"; require("firebase/firestore") const firebaseConfig = { *configuration* }; // Initialize Firebase firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); var db = ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the wrong package?

### Installation

```
# Install & setup the app module
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app

# Install the firestore module
yarn add @react-native-firebase/firestore
```

### Usage

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const usersCollection = firestore().collection('Users');
```

https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage